# Rubyで文字列を数値にするときにnilを返したい

Tags: ruby

rubyで文字列を数値に変換する際、"100".to_i でやるかと思います。

"100a".to_iなど数値じゃない場合は、そこまでを変換し、
もしくは"aa".to_iは0を返却する仕様かと思います。

そこを文字が含まれている場合はnilを返すようなメソッドを作りたいと思っています。

下記、コードのようにrescueで拾ってやると簡単にできそうですが、
rescueを使わない方法はないでしょうか？あまりにもイケてないコードですので。。。

```
Integer("aa") rescue nil
```

Answer (score 4):

rescueを使わない方法は無理に考えればなにかあるかもしれませんが、

```
Integer(str) rescue nil
```

はRubyを読み書きできる人ほとんど全員に明確に意図が通じる明瞭簡潔なコードなので、余計なことはしないほうがいいです。

公式リファレンスの[Time.parse](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Time/s/parse.html)にも使用例があるように、後置rescueはこのような場合の一般的な使用法です。

Answer (score 2):

`Integer(str) rescue nil`でメソッドを作ると、

```
irb(main):009:0> def to_i(str)
irb(main):010:1>   Integer(str) rescue nil
irb(main):011:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):012:0> to_i "a"
=> nil
irb(main):013:0> to_i "10a"
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> to_i "10"
=> 10
```

↑このあたりまではよいのですが、

```
irb(main):015:0> to_i "010"
=> 8
irb(main):016:0> to_i "0x10"
=> 16
```

↑このへんの動きがちょっと意図した挙動にならないかもしれません。

というわけで、正規表現とかで弾いてやるのが良いかなと思いました。

```
irb(main):022:0> def to_i(str)
irb(main):023:1>   str.to_i if str =~ /\A-?(?:\d|[1-9]\d+)\z/
irb(main):024:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):025:0> to_i "a"
=> nil
irb(main):026:0> to_i "10a"
=> nil
irb(main):027:0> to_i "10"
=> 10
irb(main):028:0> to_i "0x10"
=> nil
irb(main):029:0> to_i "010"
=> nil
```

参考にしてみてください。

Comment: そのコードだと`"-0"`が弾かれてしまいます。 `"0"`の扱いを分離せずに`/\A-?(?:\d|[1-9]\d+)\z/`で良いのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。"-0"って日常生活じゃ書かないな〜と思いましたが、`Integer("-0")`はゼロを返しますね。というわけでコードを更新しておきました。

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "100a"
str =~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? str.to_i : nil
```